# I can't add html elements dynamically in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have this javascript code to add html elements dynamically. It works perfectly in chrome but it doesn´t work in IE, nothing happens, just seems to add spaces that are maybe divs. Please Help Me!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var numero = 0;

evento = function (evt) {
    return (!evt) ? event : evt;
}


addCampo = function () {

    nDiv = document.createElement('div');

    nDiv.className = 'material';

    nDiv.id = 'material' + (++numero);

    nTabla = document.createElement('table');
    nTabla.width = '800';
    nTabla.cellPadding = '3';
    nTabla.cellSpacing = '0';
    nTabla.id = 'formularioContacto';
    nTR = document.createElement('tr');
    nTD4 = document.createElement('td');
    nTD4.className = 'labelEntrega';
    nTD5 = document.createElement('td');
    nTD5.className = 'labelEntrega';
    nTD6 = document.createElement('td');
    nTD6.className = 'labelEntrega';
    nTD7 = document.createElement('td');
    nTD7.className = 'labelEntrega';
    nTD8 = document.createElement('td');
    nTD8.className = 'labelEntrega';
    nTD9 = document.createElement('td');
    nTD9.className = 'labelEntrega';
    nIMG = document.createElement('img');
    nIMG.src = '../../images/btnBuscar1.gif';
    nIMG.width = '100';
    nIMG.height = '28';
    nIMG.name = 'imagen[]';
    nIMG.border = '0';
    nIMG.vAlign = 'bottom';

    nCampo = document.createElement('input');
    nCampo.name = 'codigo' + (numero);
    nCampo.type = 'text';
    nCampo.size = '10';
    nCampo.id = 'formularioContactoCampoCodigo' + (numero);

    var onchange1 = "buscaMateriales(this,";
    var onchange2 = numero;
    var onchange3 = ")";
    var onchange = onchange1 + onchange2 + onchange3;

    nCampo.setAttribute('onchange', onchange);
    //nCampo.style = 'font-family:Arial';



    nCampo1 = document.createElement('input');
    nCampo1.name = 'unidad' + (numero);
    nCampo1.type = 'text';
    nCampo1.size = '10';
    nCampo1.id = 'formularioContactoCampoUnidad' + (numero);
    //nCampo1.style = 'font-family:Arial';
    nCampo1.readOnly = 'readonly';

    nCampo4 = document.createElement('input');
    nCampo4.name = 'id' + (numero);
    nCampo4.type = 'hidden';
    nCampo4.size = '10';
    nCampo4.id = 'formularioContactoCampoID' + (numero);
    //nCampo4.style = 'font-family:Arial';
    nCampo4.readOnly = 'readonly';


    nCampo2 = document.createElement('input');
    nCampo2.name = 'cantidad' + (numero);
    nCampo2.type = 'text';
    nCampo2.size = '5';
    nCampo2.id = 'formularioContactoCampoCantidad';
    //nCampo2.style = 'font-family:Arial';

    nCampo3 = document.createElement('input');
    nCampo3.name = 'descripcion' + (numero);
    nCampo3.type = 'text';
    nCampo3.size = '50';
    nCampo3.id = 'formularioContactoCampoDescripcion' + (numero);
    //nCampo3.style = 'font-family:Arial';
    nCampo3.readOnly = 'readonly';

    a1 = document.createElement('a');
    a1.name = nDiv.id;
    a1.href = '../../include/consultarMaterial.php?id=' + (numero);
    a1.target = '_blank';


    a = document.createElement('a');

    a.name = nDiv.id;

    a.href = '#';

    a.onclick = elimCamp;

    a.innerHTML = 'Eliminar';

    nDiv.appendChild(nTabla);
    nTabla.appendChild(nTR);

    nTR.appendChild(nTD4);
    nTD4.appendChild(nCampo);
    nTD4.appendChild(nCampo4);
    nTR.appendChild(nTD5);
    nTD5.appendChild(nCampo1);
    nTR.appendChild(nTD6);
    nTD6.appendChild(nCampo2);
    nTR.appendChild(nTD7);
    nTD7.appendChild(nCampo3);
    nTR.appendChild(nTD8);
    nTD8.appendChild(a1);
    a1.appendChild(nIMG);

    nTR.appendChild(nTD9);
    nTD9.appendChild(a);

    container = document.getElementById('adjuntos');
    container.appendChild(nDiv);
}

elimCamp = function (evt) {
    evt = evento(evt);
    nCampo = rObj(evt);
    div = document.getElementById(nCampo.name);
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}

rObj = function (evt) {
    return evt.srcElement ? evt.srcElement : evt.target;
}
</script>
```

Comment: try formatting your code first, then google "javascript debugging" and start reading.

Comment: (-1) @brian's comment is snarky but I have to agree. Throwing a wall of code at people and saying  "doesn't work" is rude, even though you may get lucky and have someone spot the problem straight away. Please in the future, show some basic debugging efforts to isolate your problem

Comment: It may help if you can reduce the code to a smaller sample, so we don't have to scroll, and on IE8 you can hit F12 to get a debugger and walk through to see if it skips anything.

Comment: thank you guys a lot!! and sorry for throwing you just the code like that! it´s the first time I ask for help and didn´t know how to do it! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

In **IE**, *you can't append* a TR element to a **TABLE** unless you first put it in a **TBODY**, **THEAD**, or **TFOOT** element.

Reference: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-171-dynamic-table-dom-gotcha-in-ie.html

@Ricardo: Here's the short version of what you need...

```
Table
  +- TBody   <=== This is REQUIRED when building a table DOM in IE
       +- TR
           +-TD
           +-TD
           +-TD

nTabla = document.createElement('table');//create your table
...
nTBody = document.createElement('tbody');//ADD THIS
...
nTR = document.createElement('tr');


nTR.appendChild(nTD);//add TDs to TRs
...
nTBody.appendChild(nTR);//add TRs to TBody
...
nTabla.appendChild(nTBody);//add TBody to Table
```

Comment: @ scunliffe Just one more question!! i don´t know if you can help me but i have an onchange attribute in an input:

var onchange1 = "buscaMateriales(this,";
 var onchange2 = numero;
 var onchange3 = ")";
 var onchange = onchange1+onchange2+onchange3;

 nCampo.setAttribute('onchange',onchange);

and it doesn´t work in IE when the input changes! just in IE! Can you help me with theses please!!??

Comment: @Ricardo - yeah, sorry but that's another IE bug you can't use .setAttribute(name, value); to set inline event handlers in IE :-(  you will need to either bind the events to the elements later on, or do... `nCampo.onchange = function(){alert('do stuff here');};`

Comment: @scunliffe thankss a lot!!! the onchange property now works great! but another thing came up! i´m hating IE so much! it happens when i submit the form the dynamically added fields won´t send the info! Think you  Could help me with that??

Comment: @Ricardo - sure thing... but lets take this "offline"... you can contact me here: http://bit.ly/apspY4